# How to dynamically add style attribute to div to change the width of div(outer or inner any)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I want to dynamically set the width of a cell in a table depending on its value. I am using fowlloing code:

Helper:

```
if(someCondition){
    var outerDivID =component.find('outerDivID');
    $A.util.addClass(outerDivID , 'widthClass');
}
```

Markup:

```
<div aura:id="outerDivID" class="slds-grid">
    <!-- some code -->
</div>
```

Style:

```
.THIS.widthClass {
    style : "width : 300px";
}
```

This is done to produce markup like follpwoing but for only some cases:

```
<div aura:id="outerDivID" class="slds-grid" style= "width : 300px">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if a top level element use:

```
.THIS.widthClass {
    width : 300px;
}
```

Otherwise use (note the space after this)

```
.THIS .widthClass {
    width : 300px;
}
```